# Android stops mediaplayer audio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I have a "click" that is high frequency, but  after 20-25 clicks the sound disappear..

```
 MediaPlayer mp;

                mp = MediaPlayer.create(mService.getApplicationContext(),R.raw.click2);
                mp.start();
            }
```

ANdroid blocks by Default this kind of loops?

Comment: Are you creating a new MediaPlayer each time the sound is to be played? Is so, why not create the player once and re-use it?

Comment: I get an error: nullpointerexception if I put that line outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't see a loop in the code you've provided, but if you actually are creating `MediaPlayer`s in a loop and not calling `release()`, then you are going to cause errors by using up too much of the available resources. I have several tips for you.

Tip #1: Don't use `mService.getApplicationContext()`, since (I assume) `mService` is a `Service` and already **is** a `Context` (`Service` inherits from `Context`). You should basically never use `getApplicationContext()`.

Tip #2: Use one `MediaPlayer` and pay attention to the [state machine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). Try something like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
...
while (whateverCondition) { // I don't know what loop construct you are using...
    mp.reset();
    mp.setDataSource(this,
        Uri.parse("android.resource://com.your.package/" + R.raw.click2);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
}
...
mp.release();
```

You will need to fill in the package name as appropriate, but it should get you on the right track.